# Javascript event handler execute all the function from the beginning

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a very strange behavior that I do not understand why it occurs

The console.log at the end is printed once at the end of the script run and then again for each event that occurs, and the tempOutput array appears three times, each time with different values.

```
    var tempOutput = []

    if (limited) {
      var selectseries = mvc.Components.getInstance('selectseries');

      selectseries.on("change", function(event) {

          let vfx = setInterval(
            function() {
              dropSelect.classList.add('pulse-on');
              setTimeout(
                function() {
                  dropSelect.classList.remove('pulse-on')
                }, 1200
              )
            }, 2400);
          defaultTokenModel.on("change:" + dropDownTyp.tokenName, function(e) {
            if (vfx) {
              clearInterval(vfx);
              document.querySelector('#drop_arrow').style.background = ''
            }
          });
        } else {
          dropSelect.setAttribute('value', '<Select ' + label + '>')
          dropSelect.classList.add('disable')
        }
      })
    }


    console.log("how much?")
    console.log(tempOutput)
```

I would expect to see the array printed once, and once "how much?"

Comment: The code you have given is wrapped inside a `function` or its in global scope. If its in global scope then its not possible having multiple logs

Comment: is wrapped inside a function

Comment: try declaring `vfx` in global scope and remove `let` from inside. And also there is parsing error one extra `}` at the end.

Comment: @MaheerAli no.. it is not the problem :(